# Trigger parameterized builds through api calls

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to trigger the Jenkins builds through API calls everything is working without parameters. 
If i am trying with parameters job is not getting triggered.

```
curl -I -u tmp:apitoken http://jenkinurl:8080/job/test02/build/buildWithParameters?token=rahul&branchName=rahul
```

Answer (score 1):

Used wrong syntax.

```
curl -I -u tmp:apitoken "http://jenkinurl:8080/job/test02/buildWithParameters?token=rahul&branchName=rahul"
```

If in the case of Multiple parameters

```
curl -I -u tmp:apitoken http://jenkinurl:8080/job/test02/build/buildWithParameters?token=rahul&param1=value&param2=value
```